# Magento setup in docker container with alpine nginx and php-fpm showing blank screen

Tags: php, magento, docker, nginx, alpine-linux

I am creating a docker file with this following docker file found on docker hub
https://github.com/lcsbaroni/magento/blob/master/2.1/Dockerfile

I have done some tweak added alpine:3.6 instead of alpine:3.5 which it is using.

After successful build I installed magento and here is the docker file command bellow.

## user php1.1 which has the alpine + nginx + php 7.1

```
FROM php:7.1
ADD ./magento2 /usr/html/
WORKDIR /usr/html/

RUN find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
RUN find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
RUN chown -R :docker .
RUN chmod u+x bin/magento
RUN composer install
CMD echo "Success"
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/docker/run.sh"]
```

> The build is succesfull and installed magento2 but now when I browse
> it the magento2 setup page loads with blank and some gray color
> background some where and the system gets totally hand. May be some
> resource problem.

**Is it the issue with php-version or  memory allocations. Stuck in this problem for 1 week ,expert advice required.**